# Freewheel identification, removal, disassemble

Tags: freewheel

I have a 2021 Schwinn High Timbre 27.5" mountain bike with a bent rear axle and grinding bearings. I need to overhaul the hub, but I cannot get the 7-speed freewheel off. I don't
know who the manufacturer of the freewheel is. The only information stamped on the inner lock ring (with the two dimples) is LX (see photo 1).

[image: Photo 1]

I purchased the Park Tool freewheel remover tool FR 1.3 because it appeared to match the dimensions/configuration of the splines (see photo 2).

[image: Photo 2]

Park Tool FR 1.3 spec is 12 spline, 22.6 mm (measure 22.55 mm) suitable for Shimano style freewheels, but the actual dimension in the freewheel is 23 mm (measured 23.07 mm). When I apply force (significant) to undo the freewheel, the tool skips splines. Three questions:

1. can anyone tell me the manufacturer, make and model of this freewheel?
2. any advice on how to get the freewheel off since the park tool doesn't work?
3. if all else fails, and I decide to disassemble (destroy) the freewheel, which way does the outer lock ring (with the four square shaped notches) turn to undo (CW or CCW)?

Comment: Do you say that someone puts 7 speed freewheels on new mountain bikes in 2021? That is a bent axle waiting to happen.

Comment: @VladimirF even the bottom of the range 7sp GT and Trek mountain bikes & hybrids have freewheels, so anything goes. It's a very, very cheap way to make a functional bicycle (as it rolls off the showroom floor). Sometimes just a few currency units saved in manufacturing and assembly lets them meet a price point.

Comment: I'd be looking for secondhand wheel to put on the bike. That spline pattern doesn't look like anything I've seen before. You could probably find a wheel with a quick release skewer, which would be an upgrade on what you have anyway, and it's likely to sport a Shimano freehub too :)

Comment: You can try shimming around your splines - depending on the space you might get away with a couple of layers of aluminium foil, or possibly something thicker.

Comment: Did you ever get it apart? And how did you accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a Falcon freewheel which would mean you would need a Park FR-7 tool. As far as disassembling the freewheel itself, the bearing race should unscrew clockwise. I don't know of a tool for that other than taking a large nail to tap at the two round indents.

Answer (score 0):

I have once removed a cheap freewheel and hub, using a cutoff wheel in a grinder.  Of course it was not fit for reuse.

The only things I was saving were the spokes and the rim off that wheel, the hub was flimsy rubbish.  (this may not be the answer you're looking for)